# Open Firefox twice (with same profile)

Tags: command-line, linux-mint, firefox, profile

There are tons of resources that tell how to run several instances of Firefox in parrallel. I can't find *any* that tells me how to configure a command (on a command line, start menu item, or panel button) so that:

- the first click opens Firefox with a predetermined profile *<--(this works!)*
- subsequent clicks opens new Firefox windows for that same profile *<--(how?!?)*

Essentially the same as choosing "File->New Window" in Firefox, except triggered from a command line. To be explicit, I do not want to involve other profiles.

My motivation is that I have lots of desktops and lots of browser windows, and often finding that one window for the profile I want is a lot harder than to just click a button that is always going to be in the same place - on the panel.

For the first bullet, I currently use the command "firefox --no-remote -P "thisprofile" %u" and it has always worked as intended. However, for the second bullet, I invariably get the error *"Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To open a new window, you must first close the existing Firefox process, or restart your system"*.

**Clarification:** I have two panel buttons that start separate Firefox profiles. These use "firefox --no-remote -P "ThisOrThatProfile" %u". If I omit any other parameters and just supply "--new-window", it correctly starts new windows *of the default profile* (whether that profile is already running or not). The thing is, I cannot figure out how to start new windows *for specific (non-default) profiles*.

Comment: So what is wrong with `firefox --new-window` ?

Comment: It works fine with the default profile, but I can't get it to work with other profiles. I've attempted to clarify my question.

Comment: I used to do it this way but I have changed to using multiple usernames to keep the mess better organized.  FYI, I am logged in to user "stackex" and can come back here easily when a step of other stuff I do gets done.

Comment: @Skaperen, by "different usernames" do you mean separate user accounts on the machine? My pc has a few "users" (all same household), but switching the logged-in user is not what I'm after (that would be "too much" of a context switch, if you follow).

Comment: @KlaymenDK i do mean different user accounts ... i do this now because Unity made easy with a drop menu.  the users are set to login w/o PW (there is no sshd running here).

Answer (score 0):

In Debian Iceweasel there is no problem with profiles. With subsequent clicks really opens new Firefox windows with the same profile

Comment: Clicks on what, panel buttons and start menu items? Could you ckeck to see what the actual command behind the icons are? I'd appreciate it.

Comment: `firefox %u` in both of them.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. I just tried that, and it does work, it does open a new *tab* every time, and a new *window* if I also supply "--new-window" --- but it works *on the default profile* and I cannot make it work "across profiles". Can *you* make it work across profiles with Debian Iceweasel?

Answer (score 0):

To open new window use:

```
firefox -new-window [url]
```

As stated in:

```
firefox --help
```

Comment: Alas, this does not seem to work when the same command includes "--no-remote" and/or "-P myprofile".

Comment: what i have done in the past is create a fake home directory on the fly and set the `HOME` environment variable to it ... firefox used it OK

Answer (score 0):

`firefox -P profilename %u`, without the `--no-remote`, works for me with several different profiles simultaneously.